# Show the following is valid in SD+: How to solve this derivation

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

**This is not Homework.l do this for fun and expand my learning.**

I am obviously having difficulties with SD+,thus l post many problems.

I am using the Logic Book

Problem has be done in SD+

Using goal analysis l thought the best idea is to create a disjunction from 1 or 2
to get F. I thought Contradiction because of
J is not the premises. But will try ND.

**My partial attempt**

Derive F =>J

1.F=>(~GvH) Assume

2.F=>G.  Assume

3.~(HvI.)  Assume

4.|J    Assume

5.|F       2R

6.| G     5,2 =>E

7.|~F v ~~G 6 DN

8.~(F & ~G) 7 DeM

...

K-2:||-F

K-1:||-J

K :|F=>J

I request help on how to do it with

Comment: The premises? 1,2,3 ?

Comment: If so, assume F and derive G from 2 and H from 1. From H, derive H or I and it's done.

Comment: 1-3 are the assumptions so l can assume J

Comment: Yes, you can assume whatever you want... But J is useless: you have to derive it.

Comment: Since you posted many similar questions here, I think you just fail to understand how natural deduction (be it in Fitch form) is supposed to work... If understanding that rather than solving these trivial problems somewhat less formally is your goal, it's probably better you look up some solved examples, be it your book or elsewhere... Also you seldom present the problem clearly here. See e.g. Mauro's first comment.

Comment: In my book assumptions are taken as premisses. I don’t like working in Fitch. I solved plenty of problems. I already stated elsewhere that I have some difficulties with.

Comment: In my book assumptions are taken as premisses. I don’t like working in Fitch. I solved plenty of problems. I already stated elsewhere that I have some difficulties with. Your argument can apply to any field. If someone is asking a question,then by implication then they fail to understand what ever field they are studying. If l knew what to do in a specific instance I would not ask. I do understand SD quite well, and somewhat less SD+.  When I do ask,l feel I am derided for my ignorance. I will try to make future inquiries clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to prove F ->J from the premises F -> (~GvH), F -> G, ~(HvI) .  The first thing to note is that since J doesn't appear in the premises, you're really saying F implies anything.  That can only hold if F is false.  So your first step is to show that F is false.

Assuming F, you obtain G and ~G v H.  ~G v H is the same as G -> H.  So, you obtain H.  But you also have ~(H v I) which is the same as ~H & ~I, which gives you ~H.  Now you have a contradiction.  Therefore, F is false.

Knowing ~F, you obtain ~F v J which is the same as F -> J.

Comment: I went through some of those derivations but didn’t get ~H Thanks

Comment: Who down voted me. What did I do to do deserve it